# reduce frame rate

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i am using cocos2d, my game is working great but after a while the frame rate is reduce more and more...

i have checked with instruments and there are no leaks or allocations..
i am not allocating anything in my game. and i remove unused frames from cache during game.

the only way it comes back to normal frame rate is if i exit the scene and return back..

i just cant understand who is the cause ! my app is done and i cant publish it like that.

any help ?????
how can i find who is the cause ????

thanks

Comment: "i am not allocating anything in my game." This statement is suspect. You must allocation SOMETHING sometime, or you wouldn't have a game. This just indicates we need a more clear explanation of what's going on.

Comment: "i remove unused frames from cache during game" <-- that is a terrible waste of performance. Sprite frames use very little memory, and removing & recreating them during gameplay will impact your framerate.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you doing in your game? There are many optimization tips, such as using `CCSpriteBatchNode` when you have lots of sprites that use the same texture, etc.

If you aren't allocing anything as you say (which I find unlikely), then perhaps you're doing some heavy (and unnecessary) game logic calculations every frame... for instance, having hundreds of sprites and you're doing something like calculate the distance between each of them every frame...

Also, what device are you using?